# Premade safari like UITextField and UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI all,

Are there any premade/ready to use UITextFields and UITexView which have the toolbar(for hiding the keyboard) and autoscrolling features just like the one safari(iphone) have.

I know its possible to make it custom but I wanted to use a builted one due to lack of time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in the iOS SDk for iPhone.

There is the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) library which has some nice controls. This a bit big for just those controls.

Comment: Any third party or third developer made?